# GitHub deployment of bigger file base with Actions and FTP Deploy

Tags: deployment, github-actions

I'm trying to setup automatic deployment from my GitHub Repo to a shared hosting provider.
My GitHub action terminates with a timeout error after ~10 minutes and 30 seconds.

I'm not sure if it is the hosting provider or GitHub causing the problem.

I tested this config on small dummy projects and it worked without errors.
The real project that I would like to deploy is a bedrock based WordPress website with a couple of plugins included, so there are over 10.000 files.

I would be very thankful if someone has any hints, how to make this work.

Here is the error from the GitHub actions console:

```
Error: Server sent FIN packet unexpectedly, closing connection.
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/runner/work/_actions/SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action/4.1.0/dist/index.js:3788:56)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:215:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1184:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
Error: Error: Server sent FIN packet unexpectedly, closing connection.
```

Here is my config yaml file:

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - staging
name:  Deploy on push to staging
jobs:
  web-deploy:
    name:  Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name:  Get latest code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Add HTTP basic auth credentials
        run: echo '${{ secrets.COMPOSER_AUTH_JSON }}' > $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/auth.json

      - name:  Install composer dependecies
        uses: php-actions/composer@v6
        env:
          ACF_PRO_KEY: ${{ secrets.ACF_PRO }}

      - name:  Sync files to server
        uses: SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action@4.1.0
        with:
          server: ${{ secrets.FTP_SERVER }}
          username: ${{ secrets.FTP_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.FTP_PASSWORD }}
          server-dir: /staging/
```

Comment: Please check this [link](https://github.com/SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action/issues/137)

Answer (score 0):

change 
name:  Sync files 
uses: SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action@2.0.0
env:
FTP_SERVER: ${{ secrets.FTP_SERVER }}
FTP_USERNAME: ${{ secrets.FTP_USERNAME }}
FTP_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.FTP_PASSWORD }}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).